# iOS accessing int from another class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, cocos2d-iphone, int

I have two classes named MainGame and YourScore. In MainGame I have a Score int that keeps the track of the score in the game. In YourScore I want to show the score in a text label.

Can I change the "Hello world" text in my label to the number of score?

This is the code i have for the text label

```
          CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Times New Roman" fontSize:32];
          label.position = ccp(screenWidth / 2 , screenHeight /1.5 );
          label.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
          [self addChild: label];
```

Comment: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Strategies+for+Accessing+Other+Nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that very easily. In the first view controller where the score is declared. Just declare it as a property like the following

`@property (nonatomic,assign) int score;`

You can access that property in the second class where you want to change the Hello world text label.

just make the object of the class and use  `label.text = classObject.score;`

Comment: In case of ARC change `assign` to `weak`.

Comment: score is int. do label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",score];

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is best to use KVO for this type of UI updating. Basically, the UI object registers as an observer for a specific property on another object. When that property changes, a message is sent to a handler on the UI object, which can use the data to update the UI. This way the model object doesn't even have to be aware of the UI object.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/kvo-and-iphone-sdk.html